# React hooks, Error handling. How should I do when using MVP(Model-view-presenter)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mvp

I'm doing a login view for my application and I have at tough time getting this right. I'm pretty new at this so the solution may be trival for you. I have a presenter and a login view, now I want to catch the error in the presenter and then send it over as prop to my view and handle it there. How should I go about solving this?

My first solution was to just solve everything in the presenter but that seemed wrong to do that because it doesn't follow the rules of MVP. I did this in the presenter :

```
try {await props.model.signIn(email, password)
}
catch (error) {
var errorMessage = error.message;
if (errorMessage.includes("password")) {
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Wrong password, try again"}
```

This works but it doesn't follow the rules of MVP.

The solution was then to use react state hooks for error handling. What I want to do is when I catch the error in the presenter, to send it down as a prop to the view then handle the error there instead.

I began by declaring the state:

```
const [error,setError] = React.useState('')
```

then in the catch I did:

```
setError(error)
```

Then I send it to my view as a prop:

```
return <LoginView onUserLogIn={handleLoginACB} error = {error} />
```

LoginView has this in the render to show the error to the user:

```
  <div id = "error">{errorHandling()}</div>
```

I then do the error handling in a function in view called errorHandling.

But then when I handle it in my view it says that the props.error is not defined. What is the proper way to send an error prop from the presenter to view, and display it?

```
import LoginView from "../views/loginView";
import React from "react";
function Login(props) {
const [error,setError] = React.useState('') 

async function handleLoginACB() {
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value
        try {
            await props.model.signIn(email, password)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message)
            setError(error)
            
          
        }

        if (props.model.currentUser != null) {
            window.location.hash = "#HomeScreen"
        }

    }

    return <LoginView onUserLogIn={handleLoginACB} error = {error} />
}

export default Login;
```

```
function LoginView(props) {


    return( <div className="loginBox">
    <img src="logo.svg" className="image blob"/>
        <form>
        <input type = "email" placeholder = "Email" id="email"></input> 
        <div><input type = "password" placeholder = "Password" id="password"></input></div>
        <div id = "error">{errorHandling}</div>
        <a href="#CreateAccount">Create a new account</a>
        
        </form>
        <button  onClick={props.onUserLogIn}>Log in</button>
</div>);

function errorHandling(){
    
    console.log(props.error.message)
    if (props.error.message.includes("password")) {
        return "Wrong password, try again"
      }

      if (props.error.message.includes("email")) {
          return "Wrong email, try again"
      }
}


}

export default LoginView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not feel `React`y. Also, I think you are overengineering this. Unless you have to manage a complex state pipeline with things like Redux and Saga, I don't feel the need to go beyond self-contained Components for most use cases.

But, I will try to make this more `React`y while trying to maintain the MVP architecture.

- `Login.jsx`

```
import LoginView from "./LoginView";
import React from "react";

// This is probably your Model in `MVP`
async function handleLoginACB(model, data) {
  const { email, password } = data;

  await model.signIn(email, password);

  return model.currentUser;
}

// This is probably your View in `MVP`
function Login(props) {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState("");

  // This is probably your Presenter in `MVP`
  function onLoginFormData(data) {
    handleLoginACB(props.model, data).then((currentUser) => {
      if (currentUser != null) {
        // TODO: probably should be using a router library
        window.location.hash = "#HomeScreen";
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      setError(e.message);
    });
  }

  return <LoginView onUserLogIn={onLoginFormData} error={error} />;
}

export default Login;
```

- `LoginView.jsx`

```
import { useState } from "react";

// Maybe this is your Presenter in `MVP`
function errorHandling(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  if (error.message.includes("password")) {
    return "Wrong password, try again";
  }

  if (error.message.includes("email")) {
    return "Wrong email, try again";
  }
}

// I think this is your View in `MVP`
function LoginView(props) {
  const { onUserLogIn, error } = props;

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (<div className="loginBox">
    <img src="logo.svg" className="image blob" />
    <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}></input>
      <div><input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"
                  onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}></input></div>
      <div id="error">{errorHandling(error)}</div>
      <a href="#CreateAccount">Create a new account</a>

    </form>
    <button onClick={() => onUserLogIn({ email, password })}>Log in</button>
  </div>);
}

export default LoginView;
```

---

## Event Handler

- `Login.jsx`

```
import LoginView from "./LoginView";
import React from "react";

async function handleLoginACB(model, data) {
  const { email, password } = data;

  await model.signIn(email, password);

  return model.currentUser;
}

function Login(props) {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState("");

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  function onFormData(data) {
    case (data.field) {
        'email': setEmail(data.value); break;
        'password': setPassword(data.value); break;
    }
  }

  function onSubmit() {
    let data = {email, password};
    handleLoginACB(props.model, data).then((currentUser) => {
      if (currentUser != null) {
        window.location.hash = "#HomeScreen";
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      setError(e.message);
    });
  }

  return <LoginView onFormData={onFormData} onSubmit={onSubmit} error={error} />;
}

export default Login;
```

- `LoginView.jsx`

```
import { useState } from "react";

function errorHandling(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  if (error.message.includes("password")) {
    return "Wrong password, try again";
  }

  if (error.message.includes("email")) {
    return "Wrong email, try again";
  }
}

function LoginView(props) {
  const { onUserLogIn, error } = props;

  return (<div className="loginBox">
    <img src="logo.svg" className="image blob" />
    <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" onChange={(e) => onFormData({field: 'email', value: e.target.value})}></input>
      <div><input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"
                  onChange={(e) => onFormData({field: 'password', value: e.target.value})}></input></div>
      <div id="error">{errorHandling(error)}</div>
      <a href="#CreateAccount">Create a new account</a>

    </form>
    <button onClick={onSubmit}>Log in</button>
  </div>);
}

export default LoginView;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sakibul. A question I'm getting this error: "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." What does this mean? I'm fairly new at react.

Comment: I think I fixed the code. The `Login` Component function cannot be async. That's why the error came up. React was expecting a Component function but instead got a promise (async/await is just syntactic sugar for Promises).

Comment: How can I move the email and password state component from loginView to the loginPresenter called login without breaking the code? Thank you for all the help btw!

Comment: you can do a sort of event handler pattern I guess. but I think you are overengineering for this use case.

Comment: Yeah it's because this is a project for school am working on. They are kinda strict with not having states in the view, only in the presenter(Login).

Comment: I re-wrote the case in the presenter like this, function onFormData(data) {
    switch (data.field) {
        case 'email': setEmail(data.email); break;
        case 'password': setPassword(data.password); break;
    }
  }       Is this correct?

Comment: Also in the view, in DOM it is complaining about the e.target.value. How can I fix that? Will only take "e" and not "e.target.value".